# how to do a if statement toString() , if its equal to each other, doesnt have to display the output in Dart Flutter (android emulator, mobile apps)

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, json, flutter

[image: example code]

```
_Percent(
  size: 60, value: .7, title: pw.Text(resume.skills[0].skils)),
_Percent(
  size: 60, value: .7, title: pw.Text(resume.skills[0 + 1].skils)),
_Percent(
  size: 60, value: .4, title: pw.Text(resume.skills[0 + 2].skils)),
_Percent(
  size: 60, value: .5, title: pw.Text(resume.skills[0 + 3].skils)),
_Percent(
  size: 60, value: .8, title: pw.Text(resume.skills[0 + 4].skils)),
]),
```

how to make it simple if statement for not display the same result?

this is the resulting output I get :

[image: output android]